# axios.get() error: true with 403 error code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I called thirdparty api in nodejs(magiceden on solana blockchain) but 403 error returned.
it does not have any UI, it's just a api function call!
'isAxiosError: true' log resulted.
The api call is performed in get method.
so I inputed the req url in the browser, and the success result shown.
I mean the url returns successful result on browser, but with axios.get() request it failed.

```
'Error: Request failed with status code 403
at createError (..\createError.js:16:15)
at settle (C:\workspace\solana-wallet-nft-track-secondary_market\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\workspace\solana-wallet-nft-track-secondary_market\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:293:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
config: {
transitional: {
  silentJSONParsing: true,
  forcedJSONParsing: true,
  clarifyTimeoutError: false
},

headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'User-Agent': 'axios/0.24.0'
},
method: 'get',
url: 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getGlobalActivitiesByQuery?q={"%24match"%3A{"txType"%3A"initializeEscrow"%2C"blockTime"%3A{"%24gt"%3A1643376700}}%2C"%24sort"%3A{"blockTime"%3A-1}}',
data: undefined
},

...
},
response: {
status: 403,
statusText: 'Forbidden',
headers: {
  date: 'Fri, 28 Jan 2022 13:33:20 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close',
  'cf-chl-bypass': '1',
  'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
  expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': '6d4a978a9f812059-NRT',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'
},
config: {
 
},
request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype],
  _eventsCount: 7,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  _closed: false,
  socket: [TLSSocket],
  _header: 'GET /rpc/getGlobalActivitiesByQuery?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22txType%22%3A%22initializeEscrow%22%2C%22blockTime%22%3A%7B%22%24gt%22%3A1643376700%7D%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22blockTime%22%3A-1%7D%7D HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: axios/0.24.0\r\n' +
    'Host: api-mainnet.magiceden.io\r\n' +
    'Connection: close\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
  _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
  agent: [Agent],
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  maxHeaderSize: undefined,
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  path: '/rpc/getGlobalActivitiesByQuery?q=%7B%22%24match%22%3A%7B%22txType%22%3A%22initializeEscrow%22%2C%22blockTime%22%3A%7B%22%24gt%22%3A1643376700%7D%7D%2C%22%24sort%22%3A%7B%22blockTime%22%3A-1%7D%7D',
  _ended: true,
  res: [IncomingMessage],
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  reusedSocket: false,
  host: 'api-mainnet.magiceden.io',
  protocol: 'https:',
  _redirectable: [Writable],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
  },
  data: ''
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
```

Comment: `statusText: 'Forbidden'` --> Need authentication? Or blocked by CORS? Edit: No, I pasted the URL in my browser and I got the JSON result directly. The error is in your code

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` is a response header, why are you adding it to the request?

Comment: It says the request for Forbidden and I don't see any credentials in the log. Why should it allow you access?

Comment: @JeremyThille — Won't be CORS, this is node.js.

Comment: Aaaah, my bad, I don't know why but I had assumed it was in a browser. But regardless, it's a public API, the URL works directly even from a browser, I'm getting a big JSON response.

Comment: Well this is interesting: It works when a browser requests it, not when a non-browser requests it (for instance, `wget` or, apparently, Node.js); it returns the 403. So there's some header that the browser is sending that it wants, apparently.

Comment: @T.J. `user-agent` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille - Turns out it's not headers, it's more subtle than that; I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The resource you're trying to use does a fairly subtle thing:

- It returns a 403 (Forbidden) response with HTML showing an error page.
- The custom HTML has embedded, obfuscated JavaScript that does some things (presumably to protect the target from DDoS attacks and the like) and then replaces the current page with the response you actually want (via `history.replaceState`).

A browser with JavaScript enabled will run the JavaScript on the error page and replace it so quickly you don't really notice. But `axios` just returns the error page to your code.

This appears to be done via CloudFlare. It may be for bot-prevention or similar. I'm sure we've all see that "CloudFlare is checking your browser..." page that appears sometimes before the real thing we requested appears. This would seem to be in a similar category.

Comment: You can see the returned result on your browser from the url:

https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/rpc/getGlobalActivitiesByQuery?q={"%24match"%3A{"txType"%3A"initializeEscrow"%2C"blockTime"%3A{"%24gt"%3A1643376700}}%2C"%24sort"%3A{"blockTime"%3A-1}}

But as i mentioned with axios.get() the response was still failed .
I think it's because of connection setting problem, not sure the correct solution

Comment: @ASSASSIN1030 - No, it's because of the way the response is done, as I described above. CloudFlare seems to be doing some fairly sophisticated stuff, but the main basis of it seems to be: returning a 403 with JavaScript in the error page that, when run, replaces the error page with the JSON.

Comment: @TJ. Crowder  -  Anyway in the browser the req url shows the success result. I think in such req mode, I can get the success result within axios.get(). But I'm not sure how to do it .
If it's because of server side problem, are there any solutions to solve that problem
?

Comment: So the JSON content should be reachable with a headless browser like Puppeteer, instead of a simple HTTP call, I assume?

Comment: @JeremyThille - I'd assume so, unless the checks CloudFlare does disallow it.

Comment: @JeremyThille - As you mentioned, it's because of CloudFlare , I think. But I called axios.get() in nodejs api function, so there is no UI and it doesnt need browser to send req.
In that case, how can i solve that problem, so that I can successfully get response with axios.get()?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem? I am facing a similar situation with POST. When I attempt the same with Postman it works once, then gets blocked with the Cloudflare error page.